# Proof that the formula $((p\to q)\land (q\to r)\land p)\to r$ is a tautology

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Write down the assumptions in a form of clauses and give a resolution proof that the formula is a tautology.

$((p\to q)\land (q\to r)\land p)\to r$

I got information that i need to use here Resolution calculus...Someone can help me?

Comment: I'm rusty in logic, but can you use $$(p\to q)\land (q\to r) \implies p \to r$$ and then use $$(p \to r) \land p \iff p \land (p \to r)$$ to rewrite $((p\to q)\land (q\to r)\land p)$ as $$ (p\land (p\to r))$$

Answer (score 3):

In order to apply [Resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_%28logic%29) we consider that :

> $\varphi \rightarrow \psi$ is a *tautology* **iff** its negation : $\varphi \land \lnot \psi$ is *unsatisfiable*.

Thus we consider the formula :

> > **(*)** $ \ ((p → q)∧(q → r)∧p) \land \lnot r$

and we apply the resolution technique to show that the new formula is *unsatisfiable*.

First, we transform into an equivalent sentence in [conjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) :

> $(\lnot p \lor q)∧(\lnot q \lor r) ∧ p \land \lnot r$

and then we build the set of [clauses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)) :

> > $\{ \lnot p \lor q \}$
> >
> > $\{ \lnot q \lor r \}$
> >
> > $\{ p \}$
> >
> > $\{ \lnot r \}$.

Now we apply the resolution rule, trying to derive the *empty clause* : $\square$.

Using first and third we derive : $\{ q \}$; using it with second we derive : $\{ r \}$.

Finally, with $\{ r \}$ and fourth : $\{ \lnot r \}$, we derive the *empty clause* : $\square$.

Thus the formula **(*)** is *unsatisfiable*, and so the original formula is a *tautology*.